# How do I use a variable to specify a column name in C#.net (MVC)

Tags: c#, .net, sql, variables

I got this table in an SQL database :

[image]

and my **code** is :

```
XXEntities db = new XXEntities();
.
.
public void editSeatsNr(string seatPostion , int BusID)
{
    var bus = db.Seats.find(BusID);

}
```

where Seats is the table name and "**seatPostion**" Holds the column name ( "A2" for example ) and BusID holds the ID ( 2 for example )

lets say i wanna edit the cell which is the second row and in the "A2" column , but the name of the column "A2" is inside a variable (which is **seatPostion** ) therefore i cant do this :

```
bus.seatPostion = "new value";
```

any idea ?

Comment: Your might need to use reflection to iterrate over all items and matching on the name. and then pass it into your query.

Comment: Im sorry im pretty new to this stuff, can u explain a little bit more how im supposed to do that ? :( and thanks

Comment: Not answering the question, but i dont like the table structure. columnns-per-seat is bad. it should be normalized to `TABLE(busID, SeatID, seatState)`. in current structure what happens when the bus-company procures a new larger bus with 10 more seats? you alter table and add 10 seats in all buses? if you are new, and need help, just ask. give more details about the problem.

Comment: Like @inquisitive said, this is bad database design, which is why you're getting such a problem in the first place. You should have a Bus table with busses, and a Seat table with seats, which has a foreign key to the buss they belong to. That way, you'll get an array in your entity instead of a whole bunch of properties you have issue finding.

Comment: @inquisitive well, i see that you realized what im trying to do so, i'll try your design even though i'll get way too many rows ( since every bus got around 50 seat and theress tons of busses) but i guess thats way better than what im doing right now, so thanks! and tobberoth since im new and i dont know alot, i'll just try inquisitive's way, thanks alot :)

Comment: dont worry about number of rows. databases are designed to handle HUGE number of rows. if done properly a million rows would feel nothing. but do remember that in any information system, the database and its design is the most crucial part. we tend too put maximum time/energy/focus in keeping database right. then comes the code and last thing we worry about is the UI. if this is a paid project then i strongly recommend taking a DB course.

Comment: @inquisitive i see, thanks for the info, and i'll keep it in mind, and no its not paid its just a project for the collage,but i got a question,  whats the statement for selecting a row depending on 2 columns values, i know how to do if it was one column value by " var bus = db.Seats.Select(u=>u.BusID==BusID );" but what if its 2 columns values ( BusID and SeatID ) ?

Comment: @user2962142 it would be var bus = db.Seats.Select(u=>u.busId==BusID && u.Id == SeatID)

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how to find out which one to use, Hope this helps

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var seatToUse = "A1";

        var items = typeof (SeatsList).GetProperties().ToList();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (item.Name == seatToUse)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Match");
            }else{
                Console.WriteLine("Does not match");
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class SeatsList
{
    public int A1 { get; set; }
    public int A2 { get; set; }
    public int B1 { get; set; }
    public int B2 { get; set; }
}
```